# Add same role in rights module gives me Integrity constraint violation error

Tags: yii

I am currently working on rights module. i add trade_company_id in authitem table. so when different company add same role it should allowed. but it gives me  Integrity constraint violation: 1062 Duplicate entry 'companyadmin' for key 'PRIMARY'. The SQL statement executed was: INSERT INTO `authitem` (`name`, `type`, `description`, `bizrule`, `data`) VALUES (:name, :type, :description, :bizrule, :data) Error.

What i should do?

Comment: What is structure of table authitem?

Comment: sorry authitem table.
 name, type, description, bizrule, data,trade_company_id. each trade_company_id may b create same role. but it doesn't allow me.

Comment: I cann't undestand why field into error 'companyadmin' if your table doesn't contain it. The error means that `companyadmin` set as PRIMARY KEY and must contain only unique values. And you trying insert data with not unique value of field `companyadmin` for table.

Comment: 'companyadmin' is role name. and it is already created with trade_company_id '1'. but now i am inserting same role with other trade_company_id '2'. And yes i found reason. In authitem table 'name' field has primary key applied. so whenever i insert same role name it gives me error.

Comment: Yes. In rights module, authitem table has primary key in name field. so it not allowed to create same role even i handle different trade_company_id wise role in yii. thanx Konstantin for help..